Why livewire component lost event subscription
My livewire component lost event subscription and I don't know why ((
Event publisher code:
use Livewire\Component;

class NodeCollapse extends Component
{
    public function toggleCollapsed(): void
    {
        $this->dispatch('node.collapse', [
            'node' => $this->id,
            'collapse' => $this->collapsed,
        ]);
    }

}

JavaScript subscriber:
document.addEventListener('node.collapse', (event) => {
    console.log('node.collapse', event)
})

This subscriber works good - event with packed data got on front.
Then Livewire subscriber:
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

class Node extends Component
{
    #[On('node.collapse')]
    public function applyCollapse(mixed $data)
    {
        ...
    }
}


This subscriber not catching event (( . Few days ago this code worked well, but for now something happened and it don't.
What's wrong?
